# "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on overrided init in custom UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, xib, ibdesignable

I'm trying to make a simple reusable component (actually totally empty, just a background color to distinguish it), but when I try to use the IBDesignable decorator to make it showable in XCode Interface Builder editor, it gives me an error :

```
Failed to render and update auto layout status for AnnounceVC: The agent crashed.
```

This error seems to come from my XIB component, and its swift class.

Here is my AnnounceBubbleView class code :

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class AnnounceBubbleView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(contentView)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)!
    }
}
```

When I go in the DiagnosticReports folder, and I find my crash, it gives me this :

```
Sleep/Wake UUID:       F0240558-7F85-40FC-ADCC-7E95493F1BAA

Time Awake Since Boot: 2700 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [3224]

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 587.35 - Device: iPhone 8 (07FC5929-A66D-4560-8FBE-39DF290CD7EB) - Runtime: iOS 12.2 (16E226) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

I tried to use

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

But it gives me the same error, and XCode won't build if I don't put an Optional or Forced value.

**EDIT**

In the case where I delete the "addSubview" part, then the UIView is not my custom view, neither on the IB or in the iOS emulator. It's a blank empty UIView

code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I don't instantiate it programmaticaly, I would like to be able to preview it in the Storyboard.

Do you have any idea ?

Feel free to help me improve my post if it's not clear enough, I'm kind of new to Swift and XCode.

Answer (score 0):

During init, the contentView hasn't been initialized yet and so is nil,
trying to perform

```
addSubview(contentView)
```

indeed cause the crash has it will try to force unwrap a nil value

if your view need to be instantiated from storyboard / nib file, you shouldn't have to add the subview in the first place

if you instantiate it programmatically you need first to instantiate the contentView before trying to call addSubview

Comment: I've done this before, but the question is "why do my UIView" stays a normal UIView ? It's blank, there's nothing. It's not my custom view

Comment: first can you confirm you instantiate it programmatically?

Comment: No I don't, I would like to place it in my storyboard, I added it in the post